# Need to update the meta_value for certain meta_key from wp_postmeta table where post_date (from wp_posts) < 'xxxx-xx-xx %'

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to update the meta_value for certain meta_key from wp_postmeta table where post_date (from wp_posts) < 'xxxx-xx-xx %'.

Such as I have some posts with meta_key(x_visibility) = meta_value(only_visible). Now I want to update all the "only_visible" to "hard_visible" for all the posts who has meta_key "only_visible" except the posts has posted last one month.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution, hope will help others.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta p, wp_posts a
SET p.meta_value = 'new meta_value'
WHERE
a.ID = p.post_id
AND a.post_date <= "2017-01-31"
AND p.meta_value = 'old meta_value';
```